# Nginx frequently exits within docker while using supervisord

Tags: docker, nginx, dockerfile, supervisord

I build an image that contains **multiple tools**(such as mysql, nginx, java, etc) with the following binary and start it through `supervisord`. It is referenced from [the project](https://github.com/liufee/docker/blob/master/Dockerfile)
However, nginx failed to start during startup

However, an error was reported when starting nginx.
The nginx build command follows

```
ARG OS_VER=7

FROM centos:$OS_VER

#nginx版本
ARG NGINX_VER=1.20.2

...
...

#安装nginx
RUN cd /usr/src \
    && curl -o nginx.tar.gz http://nginx.org/download/nginx-${NGINX_VER}.tar.gz -L \
    && mkdir nginx && tar -xzvf nginx.tar.gz -C ./nginx --strip-components 1 \
    && cd nginx \
    && ./configure --prefix=/usr/local/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log \
        --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock \
        --user=nginx --group=nginx --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_flv_module --with-http_stub_status_module \
        --with-http_gzip_static_module --http-client-body-temp-path=/tmp/nginx/client/ \
        --http-proxy-temp-path=/tmp/nginx/proxy/ \
        --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/tmp/nginx/fcgi/ \
        --with-pcre --with-http_dav_module \
    && make && make install \
    && useradd nginx \
    && mkdir -p -m 777 /tmp/nginx \
    && echo "#!/bin/sh" > /etc/init.d/nginx \
    && echo "#description: Nginx web server." >> /etc/init.d/nginx \
    && echo -e "case \$1 in \n\
            restart): \n\
                /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s reload \n\
                ;; \n\
            stop): \n\
                /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -s stop \n\
                ;; \n\
            *): \n\
                /usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx \n\
                ;; \n\
        esac \n" >> /etc/init.d/nginx \
    && chmod +x /etc/init.d/nginx \
    #&& sed -i "3a daemon off;" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    #&& sed -i "s/index  index.html index.htm;/index  index.php index.html index.htm;/" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    #&& sed -i "s/# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000/location ~ \.php\$ { \nfastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;\nfastcgi_index  index.php;\nfastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  \$document_root\$fastcgi_script_name;\ninclude fastcgi_params;\n }/" /etc/nginx/nginx.conf \
    && echo "<?php phpinfo()?>" > /usr/local/nginx/html/index.php \
    # && rm -rf /etc/nginx && cp -rf /usr/src/etc/nginx /etc/nginx \
    && mkdir -m 777 -p /var/log/nginx \
    && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx.tar.gz && rm -rf /usr/src/nginx

RUN echo [supervisord] > /etc/supervisord.conf \
    && echo nodaemon=true >> /etc/supervisord.conf \
    && echo user=root >> /etc/supervisord.conf \
    \
    && echo [program:nginx] >> /etc/supervisord.conf \
    && echo command=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx >> /etc/supervisord.conf \
    \
    && echo [program:crond] >> /etc/supervisord.conf \
    && echo command=/usr/sbin/crond -n >> /etc/supervisord.conf \

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord"]
```

The error at startup is as follows

```
2022-04-19 10:40:44,652 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2022-04-19 10:40:45,656 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 117
2022-04-19 10:40:45,658 INFO spawned: 'crond' with pid 118
2022-04-19 10:40:46,094 INFO exited: crond (exit status 254; not expected)
2022-04-19 10:40:46,173 INFO gave up: crond entered FATAL state, too many start retries too quickly
2022-04-19 10:40:46,673 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-19 10:40:48,175 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2022-04-19 10:40:49,178 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 131
2022-04-19 10:40:50,194 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-19 10:40:51,695 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2022-04-19 10:40:52,699 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 132
2022-04-19 10:40:53,720 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
2022-04-19 10:40:55,221 INFO exited: nginx (exit status 1; not expected)
2022-04-19 10:40:56,224 INFO spawned: 'nginx' with pid 133
2022-04-19 10:40:57,241 INFO success: nginx entered RUNNING state, process has stayed up for > than 1 seconds (startsecs)
```

> *crond* stops restarting, *nginx* keeps exiting

What are the reasons for the above two errors and how to solve them?

I really appreciate any help with this.

Comment: There's a [prebuilt Docker Hub nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx).  Can you run that in a second container?  That will have a much simpler Docker setup, it will be easier to manage, and you can directly look at its `docker logs` to debug it.

Comment: @DavidMaze Thank you for your reply. I am sorry that I did not make it clear before. I have revised my question. Nginx is just one of the tools in my container, so I don't want to directly leverage an image of a service as the base image

Comment: Instead of trying to build one container with lots of tools in it, it's often easier to build a setup with several containers running only one program each.  That will let you use the standard images as bases and avoid the complexity of supervisord.  Tools like Docker Compose are good for launching multiple containers in parallel.

Comment: I know that containers are best kept simple, but this multi-tool requirement is not up to me